# Javascript Regular expression for checking pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, regular-language

I am using ng-pattern to check for a regular expression 
The pattern should contain 3 letters and 2 numbers in a group.

Example 
**G-31SSD** or **G-EEE43**

I am currently using pattern which matches only the second one

```
 ng-model="newGroup.groupCode" ng-pattern="/^\b[gG][-][a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}\b$/"
```

How can I make it to check for both the condition or can I write OR condition for *ng-pattern*

Comment: Checkout http://regexpal.com/ and http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternation `|` with a non-capturing group `(?:...)`

```
^[gG]-(?:[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}|\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3})$
```

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/Nni5eElnMk)

Answer (score 2):

```
^[gG]-\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}$|^[gG]-[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}$
```

or you also use

```
^[gG]-(?:(?:\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3})|(?:[a-zA-Z]{3}\d{2}))$
```

Try this.this will fulfill both the conditions.You just have to use an `|` operator which will match both types.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dV8uP2/2